# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject c#

Tags: c#, json, mvvm, deserialize

Hola amigos quiero deseralizar un json de un api de pokemon
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto
, pero tengo problemas utilice esta herramienta para convertir ese json en un clase modelo con https://www.jsonutils.com/ , le hice algunos ajustes por que note que creaba muy bien la clase, pero aun cuando le ponga la conversion original mi error a hacer

> ```
> var respContent = await respPokeApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
>   var json_d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PokemonDetail>>(respContent);
> ```

siempre es

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Pokedex.Core.Models.PokemonDetail]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'abilities', line 1, position 13.'

es error por deseralizar

Esta es la respuesta de la poke api

```
{
"abilities": [
    {
        "ability": {
            "name": "imposter",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/150/"
        },
        "is_hidden": true,
        "slot": 3
    },
    {
        "ability": {
            "name": "limber",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/7/"
        },
        "is_hidden": false,
        "slot": 1
    }
],
"base_experience": 101,
"forms": [
    {
        "name": "ditto",
        "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/132/"
    }
],
"game_indices": [
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "white-2",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/22/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "black-2",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/21/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "white",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/18/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "black",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/17/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "soulsilver",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/16/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "heartgold",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/15/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "platinum",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/14/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "pearl",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/13/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "diamond",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/12/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "leafgreen",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/11/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "firered",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/10/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "emerald",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/9/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "sapphire",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/8/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "ruby",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/7/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "crystal",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/6/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "silver",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/5/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 132,
        "version": {
            "name": "gold",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/4/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 76,
        "version": {
            "name": "yellow",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/3/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 76,
        "version": {
            "name": "blue",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/2/"
        }
    },
    {
        "game_index": 76,
        "version": {
            "name": "red",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/1/"
        }
    }
],
"height": 3,
"held_items": [
    {
        "item": {
            "name": "metal-powder",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/item/234/"
        },
        "version_details": [
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "ultra-sun",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/29/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "moon",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/28/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "y",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/24/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "x",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/23/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "white-2",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/22/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "black-2",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/21/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "white",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/18/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "black",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/17/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "soulsilver",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/16/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "heartgold",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/15/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "platinum",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/14/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "pearl",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/13/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "diamond",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/12/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "leafgreen",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/11/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "firered",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/10/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "emerald",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/9/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "sapphire",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/8/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 5,
                "version": {
                    "name": "ruby",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/7/"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item": {
            "name": "quick-powder",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/item/251/"
        },
        "version_details": [
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "ultra-sun",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/29/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "moon",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/28/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "y",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/24/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "x",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/23/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "white-2",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/22/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "black-2",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/21/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "white",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/18/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "black",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/17/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "soulsilver",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/16/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "heartgold",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/15/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "platinum",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/14/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "pearl",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/13/"
                }
            },
            {
                "rarity": 50,
                "version": {
                    "name": "diamond",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version/12/"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"id": 132,
"is_default": true,
"location_area_encounters": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/132/encounters",
"moves": [
    {
        "move": {
            "name": "transform",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move/144/"
        },
        "version_group_details": [
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "ultra-sun-ultra-moon",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/18/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "sun-moon",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/17/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/16/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "x-y",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/15/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "black-2-white-2",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/14/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "xd",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/13/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "colosseum",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/12/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "black-white",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/11/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "heartgold-soulsilver",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/10/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "platinum",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/9/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "diamond-pearl",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/8/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "firered-leafgreen",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/7/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "emerald",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/6/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "ruby-sapphire",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/5/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "crystal",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/4/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "gold-silver",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/3/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "yellow",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/2/"
                }
            },
            {
                "level_learned_at": 1,
                "move_learn_method": {
                    "name": "level-up",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move-learn-method/1/"
                },
                "version_group": {
                    "name": "red-blue",
                    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/version-group/1/"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"name": "ditto",
"order": 197,
"species": {
    "name": "ditto",
    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/132/"
},
"sprites": {
    "back_default": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/132.png",
    "back_female": null,
    "back_shiny": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/back/shiny/132.png",
    "back_shiny_female": null,
    "front_default": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/132.png",
    "front_female": null,
    "front_shiny": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/132.png",
    "front_shiny_female": null
},
"stats": [
    {
        "base_stat": 48,
        "effort": 0,
        "stat": {
            "name": "speed",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/6/"
        }
    },
    {
        "base_stat": 48,
        "effort": 0,
        "stat": {
            "name": "special-defense",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/5/"
        }
    },
    {
        "base_stat": 48,
        "effort": 0,
        "stat": {
            "name": "special-attack",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/4/"
        }
    },
    {
        "base_stat": 48,
        "effort": 0,
        "stat": {
            "name": "defense",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/3/"
        }
    },
    {
        "base_stat": 48,
        "effort": 0,
        "stat": {
            "name": "attack",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/2/"
        }
    },
    {
        "base_stat": 48,
        "effort": 1,
        "stat": {
            "name": "hp",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/1/"
        }
    }
],
"types": [
    {
        "slot": 1,
        "type": {
            "name": "normal",
            "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/1/"
        }
    }
],
"weight": 40
```

}

Este es mi modelo

```
namespace Pokedex.Core.Models
```

{

```
public class ability
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class abilities
{
    public ability Ability { get; set; }
    public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
    public int Slot { get; set; }
}

public class Form
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Version
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class GameIndice
{
    public int GameIndex { get; set; }
    public Version Version { get; set; }
}

public class Move
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class MoveLearnMethod
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class VersionGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class VersionGroupDetail
{
    public int LevelLearnedAt { get; set; }
    public MoveLearnMethod MoveLearnMethod { get; set; }
    public VersionGroup VersionGroup { get; set; }
}

public class Moves
{
    public Move Move { get; set; }
    public IList<VersionGroupDetail> VersionGroupDetails { get; set; }
}

public class Species
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Sprites
{
    public string BackDefault { get; set; }
    public object BackFemale { get; set; }
    public string BackShiny { get; set; }
    public object BackShinyFemale { get; set; }
    public string FrontDefault { get; set; }
    public object FrontFemale { get; set; }
    public string FrontShiny { get; set; }
    public object FrontShinyFemale { get; set; }
}

public class Stat
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Stats
{
    public int BaseStat { get; set; }
    public int Effort { get; set; }
    public Stat Stat { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Types
{
    public int Slot { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}

public class PokemonDetail
{
    public IList<abilities> Abilities { get; set; }
    public int BaseExperience { get; set; }
    public IList<Form> Forms { get; set; }
    public IList<GameIndice> GameIndices { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public IList<object> HeldItems { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
    public string LocationAreaEncounters { get; set; }
    public IList<Move> Moves { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public Species Species { get; set; }
    public Sprites Sprites { get; set; }
    public IList<Stat> Stats { get; set; }
    public IList<Type> Types { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
}
```

}

y ya por ultimo aqui donde lo ejecuto

```
        public async Task<IList<PokemonDetail>> GetPokemonDetail(string u)
    {
        var uri = u;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var respPokeApi = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        var pokemondetail = new List<PokemonDetail>();

        if (respPokeApi.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var respContent = await respPokeApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var json_d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PokemonDetail>>(respContent);

            pokemondetail = json_d;
        }

        return pokemondetail;
    }
```

Comment: Visual Studio tiene la opcion para pegar un json o xml y transformarlo en clases.

Comment: Cuando utilizas jsonutils.com la misma te deja configurar una serie de opciones, creo que lo que te falta es darle ckeck a Pascal Case y en la lista de Property Attributes selecionar JsonProperty o DataMember, cual sea tu caso.

Comment: Te esta forma todas las propiedades que lleven un guion bajo, por ejemplo (IsHidden de la clase abilities en realidad en el json es is_hidden) estaran en el atributo de la propiedad y el serializador sabra cual debe utilizar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu modelo parece ser incorrecto. Prueba con este modelo que he generado esta [herramienta](https://app.quicktype.io/?l=csharp) online.

```
 public partial class PokemonDetail
    {
        [JsonProperty("abilities")]
        public Ability[] Abilities { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("base_experience")]
        public long BaseExperience { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("forms")]
        public Species[] Forms { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("game_indices")]
        public GameIndex[] GameIndices { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("height")]
        public long Height { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("held_items")]
        public HeldItem[] HeldItems { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("is_default")]
        public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("location_area_encounters")]
        public Uri LocationAreaEncounters { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("moves")]
        public Move[] Moves { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("order")]
        public long Order { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("species")]
        public Species Species { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sprites")]
        public Sprites Sprites { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("stats")]
        public Stat[] Stats { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("types")]
        public TypeElement[] Types { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("weight")]
        public long Weight { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Ability
    {
        [JsonProperty("ability")]
        public Species AbilityAbility { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("is_hidden")]
        public bool IsHidden { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("slot")]
        public long Slot { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Species
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public Uri Url { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class GameIndex
    {
        [JsonProperty("game_index")]
        public long GameIndexGameIndex { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("version")]
        public Species Version { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class HeldItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("item")]
        public Species Item { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("version_details")]
        public VersionDetail[] VersionDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class VersionDetail
    {
        [JsonProperty("rarity")]
        public long Rarity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("version")]
        public Species Version { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Move
    {
        [JsonProperty("move")]
        public Species MoveMove { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("version_group_details")]
        public VersionGroupDetail[] VersionGroupDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class VersionGroupDetail
    {
        [JsonProperty("level_learned_at")]
        public long LevelLearnedAt { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("move_learn_method")]
        public Species MoveLearnMethod { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("version_group")]
        public Species VersionGroup { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Sprites
    {
        [JsonProperty("back_default")]
        public Uri BackDefault { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("back_female")]
        public object BackFemale { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("back_shiny")]
        public Uri BackShiny { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("back_shiny_female")]
        public object BackShinyFemale { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("front_default")]
        public Uri FrontDefault { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("front_female")]
        public object FrontFemale { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("front_shiny")]
        public Uri FrontShiny { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("front_shiny_female")]
        public object FrontShinyFemale { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Stat
    {
        [JsonProperty("base_stat")]
        public long BaseStat { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("effort")]
        public long Effort { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("stat")]
        public Species StatStat { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TypeElement
    {
        [JsonProperty("slot")]
        public long Slot { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public Species Type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

También he corregido la declaración de tu método ya que el json no es una lista sino es un objeto que contiene más datos.

```
public async Task<PokemonDetail> GetPokemonDetail(string u) 
{
  var uri = u;
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  var respPokeApi = await client.GetAsync(uri);
  var pokemondetail =  PokemonDetail();

  if (respPokeApi.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    var respContent = await respPokeApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    pokemondetail = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PokemonDetail>(respContent);
  }

  return pokemondetail;
}
```